# Javascript: call object method using string only

Tags: javascript, function

This code doesn't work.

```
var Modal = {
    init: function() {
        console.log("test");
    }
}
var objMethod = "Modal.init";
window[objMethod]();
```

I saw some answers that it can be called using this but I want to know how it can be called without using the object.

```
Modal["init"]();
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.  The code in your example tries to access a property called "Modal.init".  There is no such property. This largely leaves us guessing as to what you actually want to do.  `window.Modal.init` exists though.  It is also accessible via `window['Modal']['init']`.  The `window.` is superfluous.  `Modal.init` and `Modal['init']` also refer to the same function.  And when you say _without using the object_, to which object are you referring?  The one assigned to `Modal`?  How do you expect to avoid "using the object"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a namespaced function, you need to use a multidimensional array. In this case it would be `window['Modal']['init']()`, which can also be expressed by splitting the `objMethod` string and using array indices:

```
var arr = objMethod.split(".");
window[arr[0]][arr[1]]();
```

```js
var Modal = {
    init: function() {
        console.log("test");
    }
}
var objMethod = "Modal.init";
var arr = objMethod.split(".");
window[arr[0]][arr[1]]();
```